# Scrapyd vs. cron + git hooks

Tags: scrapy

I have a project with obout 30 spiders, all scheduled via cron job. Whenever I want to deploy a project I git push to production where a hook will put the files in place.

Now I came accross scrapyd which seems to do both in a more soffisticated way by egifying the scraper and deploying it to the production environment. Looking at the code it seems that this project has come to a halt about 3 years ago. I am wondering if there is an advantage to switch to scrapyd and what the reason is for this code to be so old and no longer under development. Scrapy itself receives regula updates in contrast.

Would you advice to use scrapyd and if yes, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using scrapyd for about 2 years, and I do prefer to use it over just launching your jobs using `scrapy crawl`:

- You can set the number of scrapers that can run at the same time using `max_proc_per_cpu. Any scrapers you launch when the max is reached, are put in a queue and launched when a spot is available.
- You have a minimalistic GUI in which you can check the queues & read the logs.
- Scheduling spiders is easily done with the api-calls. Same for listing the spiders, cancelling spiders, ...
- You can use http cache even when running multiple spiders at the same time
- You can deploy on multiple servers at once if you want to spread out your crawls over different servers

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How did you install it? I tried it on ubuntu, but it is not within the apt packages. The docs are missing as well: https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#installing-scrapyd-in-ubuntu Then I tried pip3 install scraypd, which installed it under my users directory instead.

Comment: I think you should install it with `sudo -H -u (scrapyd-username) pip3 install --user scrpayd`, or `sudo -H pip3 install scrapyd` if you want to install it for all users

Comment: Thank you, the -H fixed it.